# Tail Select using Check box

Tags: javascript

I want to perform multiple tail select using checkbox than a dropdown , i checked a code ,but i was not able to convert it to checkbox , Can anyone help me .

```js
var projects = tail.select("select.projects", {
  deselect: true,
  multiContainer: ".projects-selected",
  multiple: true,
});
projects.config("multiple", false, true);
projects.on('change', changeFirst);

let tests = tail.select("select.tests", {
  multiContainer: ".tests-selected",
  disabled: true
});

function getData() {
  var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 5;
  var randomEntry = function() {
    var tmp = CryptoJS.MD5(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000).toString()).toString();
    console.log(tmp);
    return {
      id: 'ID_' + tmp,
      name: tmp
    };
  };
  return Array.from({
    length: size
  }, randomEntry);
}

function changeFirst(opt, event) {
  if (event == 'select') {
    let data = getData();
    let items = {};
    data.forEach(function(entry) {
      items[entry.id] = entry.name
    });
    tests.config('items', items);
    tests.config('disabled', false);
  } else if (event == 'unselect') {
    tests.config('disabled', true);
    tests.config('items', {});
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <select class="projects">
    <option>Project 1</option>
    <option>Project 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <span class="projects-selected"></span>
  <span class="tests-selected"></span>
</div>
```

i tried editing this code , but am not getting what i wanted , so can anyone help me to sort it out .

Output should be something like this :
[image: output]

so when we click on the span generated  it should unselect . , but whatever  try to provide checkbox is not working

NOTE :

**tail. select is a rewritten version of the jQuery tail. select plugin that can be used to beautify & enhance the default select box with no dependency**

[https://www.cssscript.com/single-multiple-select-tail/#:~:text=Description%3A,select%20box%20with%20no%20dependency.](https://www.cssscript.com/single-multiple-select-tail/#:%7E:text=Description%3A,select%20box%20with%20no%20dependency.)

I don't know whether this can be done using tail.select , If not possible , can anyone suggest any other way to do this .

Comment: What is `tail`?

Comment: tail. select is a rewritten version of the jQuery tail. select plugin that can be used to beautify & enhance the default select box with no dependency.     @Barmar

Comment: You should add a link to the documentation in the question, as most JS programmers will not be familiar with it.

Comment: done , added a link @Barmar

Comment: I would like to note a change for the `tail.select` library. The old repository is gone completely and the new version is here -

https://github.com/wolffe/tail.select.js

Also, the demo is available here -

https://getbutterfly.com/tail-select/

Since the plugin has disappeared, a few months ago, I have updated it to version 0.5.20 and an ES6 version 0.6 is in the works. I am maintaining this plugin/library full time.